# $widget._getNewPrices js error magento 2 color swatches

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

> When i click on color swatches i got error **$widget._getNewPrices is not function** on console and image does not change.

[image]

**can anyone  help me to solve this error ?**

Thanks

Comment: please show error

Comment: @Msquare i have update my question